# confusing Android SDK error: static reference to non-static method

Tags: java, android, static, bluetooth

Can someone help explain why in line 6 of the following code (contained in a .java file I'm working on in the ADT Eclipse IDE) I'm getting the error marker:

"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getRemoteDevice(String) from the type BluetoothAdapter"

```
import android.bluetooth.*;

public final class bluetooth{

    void initConnection(String address){
         BluetoothSocket sock = BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address).createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB);
    }
}
```

What in the above code makes anything static?  And why am I not handed the same error for the use of the `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` method of BluetoothDevice?

Comment: your final modifier makes it static since no changes can be made to this at runtime, you need to create an instance of the BluetoothSocket class before doing things like this

Comment: void initConnection(String address) change to                    static void initConnection(String address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't can't call getRemoteDevice() on the BluetoothAdapter class, it's not a static method. You need an instance, like this:

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothSocket sock = adapter.getRemoteDevice(address)
    .createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB);
```

Comment: ahh, worked like a charm. i was looking at it "backwards," thinking i needed an instance of the return type instead of the method's class.  Thanks